# Strange browser window locking with jQuery, scrollTop, and #anchors

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm experiencing a strange issue in multiple browsers when using scrollTop to navigate to anchor points. The window scrolls correctly, but becomes locked in a way that is difficult to break. Here is a video of the problem in Safari, but the same thing happens in Chrome:

http://www.screencast.com/t/vyM16IlVb

Notice how the browser window fights the scroll, whether I scroll gently or aggressively. It will break eventually, but I can't figure out what makes that possible.

I'm using a jQuery function for smooth scrolling anchor links that I found on the web. It scrolls just fine, generally, aside from this. Here is that script:

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Any thoughts on what this might be would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like multiple scroll animations are being accumulated.  Try adding `stop()` like this:  `$('html,body').stop().animate(...`

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, no help. How would scroll animations accumulate?

Comment: jQuery queues animations, so it can sometimes be useful to stop an animation that's in progress before starting a new one.  We may need to see more code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if animate is still trying to reach it's target scroll position. jQuery calculates the offset().top relative to the current scroll position which at that point is a position outside of the screen, or negative. So when you queue animate to reach a negative scroll position it will never reach it.

Try a simple check before triggering the animation and prevent negative targets.

```
 var top = target.offset().top;

 $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: top < 0 ? 0 : top
 }, 1000);
```

But this wont scroll to your desired location if the page has scrolled, to fix this take into consideration the current scroll position like this:

```
var top = target.offset().top + $(window).scrollTop();

 $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: top // top should never be negative this way
 }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried that solution, but the result was even more strange: the scroll goes to the top, but then bounces between the top and the original click 6 times. Watch: [http://www.screencast.com/t/aWkiqdSdYT](http://www.screencast.com/t/aWkiqdSdYT)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had the exact same code block repeated in my sitewide script file, so including it locally (two instances of the same script) was causing a conflict. Removing the local copy caused everything to work properly.